# IAM Capability Check While Launching CFT Using API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

i am trying to launch a CFT using the AWS Cloud Trail API. The problem is, when i launch the CFT directly into the AWS console it presents me with a IAM capability check screen
[image]

how can i handle this check box while using the API.

Answer (score 2):

Using the API

> Capabilities.member.N
>
> A list of values that you must specify before AWS CloudFormation can create certain stacks. Some stack templates might include resources that can affect permissions in your AWS account, for example, by creating new AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) users. For those stacks, you must explicitly acknowledge their capabilities by specifying this parameter.
>
> The only valid values are CAPABILITY_IAM and CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM. The following resources require you to specify this parameter: AWS::IAM::AccessKey, AWS::IAM::Group, AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile, AWS::IAM::Policy, AWS::IAM::Role, AWS::IAM::User, and AWS::IAM::UserToGroupAddition. If your stack template contains these resources, we recommend that you review all permissions associated with them and edit their permissions if necessary.
>
> If you have IAM resources, you can specify either capability. If you have IAM resources with custom names, you must specify CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM. If you don't specify this parameter, this action returns an InsufficientCapabilities error.
>
> For more information, see [Acknowledging IAM Resources in AWS CloudFormation Templates.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-iam-template.html#capabilities)
>
> Type: Array of strings
>
> **Valid Values: CAPABILITY_IAM | CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_CreateStack.html

Using the AWS CLI

> --capabilities (list)
>
> A list of values that you must specify before AWS CloudFormation can create certain stacks. Some stack templates might include resources that can affect permissions in your AWS account, for example, by creating new AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) users. For those stacks, you must explicitly acknowledge their capabilities by specifying this parameter.
> The only valid values are **CAPABILITY_IAM and CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM** . The following resources require you to specify this parameter: AWS::IAM::AccessKey , AWS::IAM::Group , AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile , AWS::IAM::Policy , AWS::IAM::Role , AWS::IAM::User , and AWS::IAM::UserToGroupAddition . If your stack template contains these resources, we recommend that you review all permissions associated with them and edit their permissions if necessary.
> If you have IAM resources, you can specify either capability. If you have IAM resources with custom names, you must specify CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM . If you don't specify this parameter, this action returns an InsufficientCapabilities error.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/create-stack.html